# SOATEST: NOt able to connect to database with the Oracle 12c drivers installed in JDBC folder

Tags: oracle12c, parasoft

I have been using Parasoft SOATEST 9.9 and was using it to develop and run my web services tests against our server(using Oracle 11g drivers). Recently we moved to use the Oracle 12c drivers(12.2.0.1) and I replaced my earlier oracle.jar to 'ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar' and made sure to point this in my Parasoft > Preferences> JDBC drivers (enclsoed screenshot of the Preferences window) and  after that when I run my tests, I am getting the below error and not able to connect to database: Can someone please help ? Thanks in advance!
[[image: SOATEST_Preferences_JDBCDriver]
Error Message:
DataSource:  oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Additional Details:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)

at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)

at com.parasoft.xtest.common.web.XTestJdbcClassLoaderProvider$WebJdbcClassLoader.loadClass(XTestJdbcClassLoaderProvider.java:68)

at com.parasoft.xtest.common.web.XTestJdbcClassLoaderProvider$WebJdbcClassLoader.loadClass(XTestJdbcClassLoaderProvider.java:59)

at com.parasoft.db.JdbcConnectionFactory.getDriverStatic(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:75)

at com.parasoft.db.JdbcConnectionFactory.getDriver(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:58)

at com.parasoft.db.JdbcConnectionFactory.getJDBCConnection(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:36)

at com.parasoft.db.AppJdbcConnectionFactory.getJDBCConnection(AppJdbcConnectionFactory.java:25)

at com.parasoft.db.VariableDbConnectionProvider.getConnection(VariableDbConnectionProvider.java:41)

at webtool.db.DbTool.doApply(DbTool.java:142)

at webtool.tool.WebTool.applyTool(WebTool.java:127)

at com.parasoft.tool.Tool.apply(Tool.java:285)

at com.parasoft.tool.Tool.getApplyResult(Tool.java:297)

at webtool.test.ToolTest.run(ToolTest.java:840)

at webtool.test.Test$4.loop(Test.java:912)

at webtool.test.execution.CompositeExecutionLoop.loop(CompositeExecutionLoop.java:60)

at webtool.test.execution.CompositeExecutionLoop.loop(CompositeExecutionLoop.java:69)

at webtool.test.execution.CompositeExecutionLoop.loop(CompositeExecutionLoop.java:69)

at webtool.test.execution.CompositeExecutionLoop.loop(CompositeExecutionLoop.java:69)

at webtool.test.execution.TestSuiteLoop.runSetUpTearDownTests(TestSuiteLoop.java:247)

at webtool.test.execution.TestSuiteLoop.runSetUpTests(TestSuiteLoop.java:221)

at webtool.test.execution.TestSuiteLoop.setup(TestSuiteLoop.java:133)

at webtool.test.execution.CompositeExecutionLoop.setup(CompositeExecutionLoop.java:109)

at webtool.test.execution.CompositeExecutionLoop.loop(CompositeExecutionLoop.java:54)

at webtool.test.execution.CompositeExecutionLoop.loop(CompositeExecutionLoop.java:69)

at webtool.test.execution.CompositeExecutionLoop.loop(CompositeExecutionLoop.java:69)

at webtool.test.execution.CompositeExecutionLoop.loop(CompositeExecutionLoop.java:69)

at webtool.test.execution.CompositeExecutionLoop.loop(CompositeExecutionLoop.java:69)

at webtool.test.Test.run(Test.java:1071)

at webtool.test.TestExecutor.run(TestExecutor.java:361)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your JDK version? ojdbc8.jar requires JDK 8. Please refer to [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03_1) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your Parasoft SOAtest v9.9 is using older version of Java (Java 7)
You have two options:

- upgrade your SOAtest to latest version (recommended - now v9.10.3)
- start soatest.exe  with option -Zjava_home {path_to_Java)

i.e:  soatest.exe -Zjava_home "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"